# Kotlin - Replace only last given String from String

Tags: java, kotlin

I'd like to replace String from another String, but only the last found String. For example:

```kotlin
"ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR".replaceLast(",", " &") // Outputs: "ONE, TWO, THREE & FOUR"
```

Comment: Hackish way: reverse the string, `replaceFirst`, re-reverse the string.

Comment: Maybe you could use a combination of `substringBeforeLast` and `substringAfterLast`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before-last.html

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Nice! Who doesn't love a good old workround solution?

Comment: @Joffrey would you mind providing an example? If you say it's not much to ask, you could answer the question with the example

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I wouldn't call this hackish. Years ago I read someone propose something similar for using regexes to match something at or near the end of a string: reverse the string, match with a carefully 'reversed' regex, and then reverse the match. They called it a "sexeger" -- regexes spelled backwards. It can be a big performance win if matching in the forward direction would result in catastrophic backtracking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To replace only the last occurrence of a substring in a Kotlin string, you can use an extension function. Here's a Kotlin extension function that accomplishes this:

**Kotlin:**

```
fun String.replaceLast(oldValue: String, newValue: String): String {
    val lastIndex = lastIndexOf(oldValue)
    if (lastIndex == -1) {
        return this
    }
    val prefix = substring(0, lastIndex)
    val suffix = substring(lastIndex + oldValue.length)
    return "$prefix$newValue$suffix"
}

fun main() {
    val input = "ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR"
    val result = input.replaceLast(",", " &")
    println(result) // Output: "ONE, TWO, THREE & FOUR"
}
```

**Java:**

```
public class Main {
    public static String replaceLast(String input, String oldValue, String newValue) {
        int lastIndex = input.lastIndexOf(oldValue);
        if (lastIndex == -1) {
            return input;
        }
        String prefix = input.substring(0, lastIndex);
        String suffix = input.substring(lastIndex + oldValue.length());
        return prefix + newValue + suffix;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR";
        String result = replaceLast(input, ",", " &");
        System.out.println(result); // Output: "ONE, TWO, THREE & FOUR"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answer, if you worked with single chars only, you could define your function like this:

```kotlin
fun String.replaceLast(oldValue: Char, newValue: Char): String =
    substringBeforeLast(oldValue) + newValue + substringAfterLast(oldValue)
```

But you may as well avoid traversing the string twice by using the function from the other answer (reusing the index).